# Check that homescreen is in foreground using shell or/and uiautomator

Tags: android, shell, automated-tests, adb, android-uiautomator

Maybe some value in `dumpsys` (had no success to find such)?

Or as kind of partial workaround check default launcher and then check that it's in foreground? But how to check what app is default launcher then?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`dumpsys activity activities` or `dumpsys  activity recents` will give you the recent activities, and if the home screen is in the foreground, then its associated launcher would show up under the entries in `Recent #0`.

As for finding out the default launcher, you would need root access since the default app information is stored under `/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml` ([source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34893/where-does-android-store-the-default-application-for-file-type-open-with-set)), and the command would be:

```
cat package-restrictions.xml | grep -B6 "android.intent.category.HOME"
```

You have to look for the value:

```
<item name="ginlemon.flowerpro/ginlemon.flower.HomeScreen" match="100000" set="3">
```

Change `B6` to a bigger value if you don't see `<item name=`.

Comment: That `cat` command would work if only you're in the `0` directory.